# How to get difference between 2 dates with different ISO format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iso8601, python-iso8601

I need to calculate the difference between 2 differently formatted ISO dates. For example, `2019-06-28T05:28:14Z` and `2019-06-28T05:28:14-04:00`. Most of the answers here focus on only one format or another, i.e `Z`-formatted.

Here is what I have attempted using this library [iso8601](https://pypi.org/project/iso8601/):

```
import iso8601

date1 = iso8601.parse_date("2019-06-28T05:28:14-04:00")
date2 = iso8601.parse_date("2019-06-28T05:28:14Z")

difference = date2 - date1

>>> datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=75600)
```

I have also tried to replace `Z` with `-00:00` but the difference is the same:

`date2 = iso8601.parse_date("2019-06-28T05:28:14Z".replace("Z", "-00:00")`

If I understand this correctly, it should show a difference of 4 hours. How do I calculate the difference in hours/days between 2 different date formats?

I am using Python 3.8.1.

Comment: ```date1 - date2 = 4:00:00```

Comment: @JoshuaNixon how do I get the numeric days from the delta object? (like 4/24 = 0.1666 days)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used Pandas module but I think is the same with iso8601.
To have the right difference I had to specify the same timezone in parsing function, as it follows:

```
import pandas as pd
date1 = pd.to_datetime("2019-06-28T05:28:14-04:00",utc=True)
date2 = pd.to_datetime("2019-06-28T05:28:14Z",utc=True)
```

Then my difference is expressed in a Timedelta format:

```
difference = (date2 - date1)
print(difference)
>> Timedelta('-1 days +20:00:00')
```

A timedelta of -1 days and 20h means 4 hours, infact if I convert the total seconds in hours I obtain:

```
print(difference.total_seconds()//3600)
>> -4
```

I hope this could be of help.

Comment: thank you. Does this mean that `date2` is earlier? Also `date1 > date2` returns `True`

Comment: nvm, I was confused for a moment, but I understand it now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is using the [`metomi-isodatetime`](https://pypi.org/project/metomi-isodatetime/) package. It's created by the [**Met Office**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Met_Office), so it *must* be standards-compliant.

Also, the package has no other dependencies, so it's 'lightweight'.

```py
from metomi.isodatetime.parsers import TimePointParser

date1_s = "2019-06-28T05:28:14Z"
date2_s = "2019-06-28T05:28:14-04:00"

date1 = TimePointParser().parse(date1_s)
print(date1)

date2 = TimePointParser().parse(date2_s)
print(date2)

datediff = date2 - date1
print(type(datediff))
print(datediff)
print(datediff.hours)
#
```

Running the above will produce the following output:

```
2019-06-28T05:28:14Z
2019-06-28T05:28:14-04:00
<class 'metomi.isodatetime.data.Duration'>
PT4H
4
```